# What is $E[1/X]$ when $X$ is a standard normal random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions

It's long time ago that I took the calculus class, so I dare to ask. If $X\sim N(0,1)$, what is $\mathbb{E}(1/X)$?
$$\mathbb{E}(1/X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1x \cdot \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}2\right) dx.$$
Can I just claim $\mathbb{E}(1/X) = 0$ as $\frac1x \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$ is an [odd function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Odd_functions) even when it is not [bounded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function)?

Comment: Isn't it an odd function?

Comment: The integral does not exist.  There is no good reason to take existence in the PV sense as relevant.

Comment: The is rather similar to asking for the expected value of the Cauchy distribution, which also gives 0 if we adopt the Cauchy PV; but that is not consider relevant/appropiate. In particular, if we use the Lebesgue integral (the sane thing to do in probability) it's clear that the integral does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

You could speak of a [Cauchy principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).  It's an integral whose positive and negative parts are both infinite, so the expected value does not exist.

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac1x e^{-x^2/2}\;dx \ge \int_0^1 \frac1x e^{-1}\;dx = \infty,
$$
and similarly
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac1x e^{-x^2/2}\;dx = -\infty.
$$

The Cauchy principal value is $0$ because it's an odd function, i.e.
$$
\lim_{a\to0+}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-a}+\int_a^\infty\right) \frac1x e^{-x^2/2} \; dx = 0.
$$

Comment: Maybe I should add that limit theorems like laws of large numbers require actual integrals to exist; Cauchy principal values aren't good enough for those.